# Pandas iteratively append row values from multiple DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to iteratively append row values from multiple columns to a new column in a new DataFrame based on a group.

My goal is to have 1 row for each customer, with 1 column for the customer's ID and 1 column for their timeline that  lists the date of each event followed by the event description, for all dates and events, in chronological order.

I have solved this with a series of dictionaries. I am searching for a clean, elegant, pandas-style way to accomplish this as this code will be run frequently with small changes to customers, events, etc.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df_have = pd.DataFrame({'Customer_ID':['customer_1','customer_1','customer_1','customer_2','customer_2'], 
                        'Event':['purchased cornflakes','purchased eggs', 'purchased waffles','sold eggs','purchased cows'],
                           'Date':['2011-06-16','2011-06-13','2011-06-09','2011-06-13','2011-06-18']})

df_have['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_have['Date'])

df_have.sort_values(['Customer_ID','Date'], inplace =True)
df_have
```

[image: df I currently have]

```
df_want = pd.DataFrame({'Customer_ID':['customer_1','customer_2'],
                       'Time_Line':[['2011-06-09,purchased waffles,2011-06-13,purchased eggs,2011-06-16,purchased cornflakes'],
                                   ['2011-06-13,sold eggs,2011-06-18,purchased cows']]})
df_want
```

[image: df I'd like to have]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Steps:*

1) Set *`Customer_ID`* to be the index axis as it would remain static throughout the operation.

2) `stack` so that *`Date`* and *`Event`* fall below one another.

3) Peform `groupby` w.r.t the index (`level=0`) and convert the only column into `list`. Since we've stacked them in this sequence, they would appear alternatingly.

---

```
# set maximum width of columns to be displayed
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 100)

df_have.set_index('Customer_ID').stack(
    ).groupby(level=0).apply(list).reset_index(name="Time_Line")
```

[image]

---

To change the order in which sequence occurs inside the `list`:

```
df_have.set_index('Customer_ID').reindex_axis(['Event', 'Date'], axis=1).stack(
    ).groupby(level=0).apply(list).reset_index(name="Time_Line")
```

[image]